# Is there a standard list of names for different arrowhead shapes?

Tags: terminology, line-art

Is there a standard list of names for different arrowhead shapes?

I don't mean Indian/Native American arrowheads, I mean arrowheads that you would find in clipart, visio, adobe, word, etc.

I just can't find anything. Some are open, some are plain triangles, others have wedges cut out of the back, the variations are endless. I'm hoping that there is some sort of standard names for these arrowhead shapes so that I don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: There are names for different arrows in fields such as mathematics and flow chart diagrams, but not in design as far as I'm aware. There would be far too many options for them all to have a distinct name.

Answer (score 3):

So, taking a clue from @zach-saucier, I started searching for flowchart and math symbol names which eventually led me to good 'ole Latex.  Latex is a way of embedding math notation into documents: word, pdf, wiki, etc.

It's a start.

Latex defines a set of arrowhead names:

- latex
- latex'
- stealth
- angle 60
- etc

[image]